# Varnish - VCL - do BAN() request on remote host

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

i have a few varnish cache's running, and want to be able to `ban()/purge()` content on the local varnish node, and from there i also want to purge the remote varnishes, so i can purge on all varnish hosts.

it should be triggerd on "POST" method calls. any chance to call a script? in that case?, or doing a BAN/POST request on the remote caches?

```
sub vcl_recv {
if(req.http.X-bypass-Cache == "yes" || req.method == "POST") {
      if(req.method == "POST") {
        ban("obj.http.X-SID ~ " +  req.http.X-SID);
        //bans local cache - AND HERE i want to purge also a few other varnish caches like
        ban("192.168.0.1:80", "obj.http.X-SID ~ " +  req.http.X-SID);
      }
      return(pass);
 }

}
```

i could do the purge/ban from anywhere else, i only need to trigger a REST-API or a local shell script to do the plumbing.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the record, there is a vmode plugin for curl bindings out there:

https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-curl/

wich enables a curl.get("http://ENDPOINT/purge.php") - call, its exactly what i needed.